# ELGG work with Social Network Analysis

Tags: elgg

If I wan to add in a Social Network Analysis in this elgg, what should I do?
I tried to find SNA plugin on web but failed.

is it possible to develop a SNA plugin for elgg by ourself?
or any recommended open source SNA tools available so i can integrated it with elgg?

thanks in advance

Comment: "Social Network Analysis" is quite an ambiguous term, can be interpreted in many ways. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What functionality do you need?

Comment: hmm..I just want to show the nodes(people) and relationship in graph form.If possible, make the features like Facebook "suggested friend"/"friend you might know" <--something like this

Comment: I'm in the middle of developing an Elgg plugin exactly for this. At the moment, unfortunately, I can't give you an estimate when will I be able to finish it. If you're interested in this plugin, follow me on Elgg Community, so you'll get notifications for my plugin uploads.

Comment: @András Szepesházi: Thanks.. i will follow up in Elgg community..

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in a Facebook like "suggested friend" feature you might try the "People from the Neighborhood" plugin from the elgg community site: http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/project/672106/developer/emdagon/people-from-the-neighborhood

It took some slight modification to get it working in Elgg 1.7 and may take more work for the upcoming Elgg 1.8. It is a simple plugin, but I have been very impressed with the quality of the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Right now the solution in 1.8 is [Suggested Friends 1.8](http://community.elgg.org/plugins/869921/1.2/suggested-friends-18x) is a updated version of "People from Neighborhood" commented by [RussellM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879213/russellm)

In the official desc says:

> A 1.8 upgrade and rename of People From The Neighborhood
>   (http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/project/672106/developer/emdagon/people-from-the-neighborhood).
>   Provides
>       dashboard widget
>       profile widget
>       suggested friends page
>       configure suggestions from friends, groups, or both   Produced for and with the support of Athabasca University, Canada